# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground(), Caused by NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm currently developping an android app for college and I'm having trouble with this.

Everytime I'm trying to list workers (trabalhadores) in the app after the button for it is pressed (TrabalhadoresMainActivity) this happens and the application closes. The problem seems to be in a NullPointer in the ArrayList of Trabalhadores but I can't find where.

I've seen questions similar to this but usually it's just an ArrayList = null type of situation, which is not my case since I start the ArrayList by new ArrayList<>().

Here's the code and error:

```
com.example.androidd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.androidd, PID: 9294
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:365)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.androidd.dto.ListaTrabalhadorPartialDTO.getTrabalhadores()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.androidd.dto.Mapper.listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO2ListaTrabalhadorPartial(Mapper.java:121)
        at com.example.androidd.controller.TrabalhadoresMainActivity$2.getResponseObject(TrabalhadoresMainActivity.java:138)
        at com.example.androidd.network.GenericGetAsyncTask.doInBackground(GenericGetAsyncTask.java:37)
        at com.example.androidd.network.GenericGetAsyncTask.doInBackground(GenericGetAsyncTask.java:15)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

MainActivity

```
public class TrabalhadoresMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    ProgressBar pb;
    ArrayList<TrabalhadorPartial> trabalhadorPartials;
    ListViewAdapterTrabalhador adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trabalhadores_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        trabalhadorPartials = new ArrayList<TrabalhadorPartial>();
        adapter = new ListViewAdapterTrabalhador(this, R.layout.listview_trabalhador_item, trabalhadorPartials);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(TrabalhadoresMainActivity.this,"Click: details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TrabalhadorPartial trabalhadorPartial = (TrabalhadorPartial) adapter.getItem(i);
                Intent intent = new Intent(TrabalhadoresMainActivity.this, TrabalhadorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Utils.MODE,Utils.ACTIVITY_MODE_DETAILS);
                intent.putExtra(Utils.ID, trabalhadorPartial.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        getTrabalhadoresFromWS();
    }
```

getTrabalhadoresFromWS (get workers from web service)

```
private void getTrabalhadoresFromWS() {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") GenericGetAsyncTask task = new GenericGetAsyncTask(pb, this) {
            protected Response getResponseObject(String httpResponse) {
                ListaTrabalhadorPartialDTO listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO = XmlHandler.deSerializeXML2ListaTrabalhadorPartialDTO(httpResponse);
                ListaTrabalhadorPartial trabalhadores = Mapper.listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO2ListaTrabalhadorPartial(listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO);
                return new Response(HttpStatusCode.OK, trabalhadores);
            }

            protected void onPostExecuteProcessDataUI(Object object) {
                if (object instanceof ListaTrabalhadorPartial) {
                    trabalhadorPartials.clear();
                    trabalhadorPartials.addAll(((ListaTrabalhadorPartial) object).getTrabalhadorPartials());
                } else {
                    trabalhadorPartials.clear();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        String address = Utils.getWSAddress(this);
        task.execute(address + "/trabalhadores");
    }
```

finally, where the problem seems to be, the Mapper

```
public static ListaTrabalhadorPartial  listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO2ListaTrabalhadorPartial(ListaTrabalhadorPartialDTO listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO) throws NullPointerException {
        ArrayList<TrabalhadorPartial> trabalhadorPartials = new ArrayList<TrabalhadorPartial>();
        ArrayList<TrabalhadorPartialDTO> trabalhadoresDTO = listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO.getTrabalhadores();
        if(trabalhadoresDTO != null) {
            for (TrabalhadorPartialDTO trabalhadorPartialDTO : trabalhadoresDTO) {
                try {
                    TrabalhadorPartial trabalhadorPartial = trabalhadorPartialDTO2TrabalhadorPartial(trabalhadorPartialDTO);
                    trabalhadorPartials.add(trabalhadorPartial);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    //does nothing. Actually, nothing is added to arraylist
                }
            }
        }
        ListaTrabalhadorPartial listaTrabalhadorPartial = new ListaTrabalhadorPartial(trabalhadorPartials);
        return listaTrabalhadorPartial;
    }
```

After debugging, noticed it crashes after the second line in this method just before "if", and the debugger goes into AsyncTask. Tried to see if the problem was in the XML Handler but no clue.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, you can check if  this `ListaTrabalhadorPartialDTO listaTrabalhadorPartialDTO = XmlHandler.deSerializeXML2ListaTrabalhadorPartialDTO(httpResponse);` returns a non-null value.